# How do I get the rest of the data in a Feature Service?

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-pro, feature-service

I have a Feature Service which serves up exactly 1,000 rows and I'm struggling to  get the rest of the information.

Using ArcGIS Pro v3 I thought maybe it's a query layer.. but that seems to be only applicable to databases, not REST services.

Then I was thinking I could import the data by means of ArcPy, but I'm not sure where to start. I mean importing feature services to file geodatabases is easy, but how do I request more data from the service?

```
...
fs = arcpy.FeatureSet()
fs.load(serviceURL)
fs.save(localCopy)
...
```

The total "rows" I'm expecting is well in excess of 30,000 so a server side limit increase is not possible.

Can someone give me a pointer in the right direction? What tool/approach/feature/function is it that I'm looking for?

Comment: The maximum feature count is a property of a service. The client won't change that. It you have control of the server, you can bump that up, but doing so to extremes might crater your server under load. If you don't have control... well, scraping features is generally a TOS violation, so before you start working the *how*, you might want to start with the *ought*. Usually there's a viable alternative.

Comment: You are are 100% correct. In this case, we have two organisations, contractually and statutorily engaged. The purpose of this exercise is troubleshooting - reconciling datasets that are supposed to be in synch all the time... *ought* is sorted :)

Comment: So then the viable alternative is by accessing the data sources directly (not through a Feature Service)

Comment: The only practical way I can see of doing that in a "non-permanent let's build a integration verification process" is to export and email. Any other data access would surely involve firewalls/accounts and a heap of other roadblocks. I think my FeatureService scraping is a fit for purpose approach. Not too taxing, and absolutely clear as to what I'm seeing, *at the source*

Answer (score 0):

The maxRecordCount parameter for the feature service needs to be updated, the default is 1000 records. Is the feature service hosted in ArcGIS Online or ArcGIS Enterprise?

ArcGIS Online: https://support.esri.com/en/technical-article/000012383

For ArcGIS Enterprise you need to change the maxRecordCount parameter in Server Manager.

Comment: Surely there must be a way to page through the next 1,000 records using arcGIS Pro?

Comment: Not sure, maybe select by attribute using OID ranges to get the required records. If the data was published as a Map Image service rather than Feature Service then you can render all 30000 records. It will likely be slow/need to be cached but is an option.